# oauth2 authentication flow on firebase functions keep saying missin required field client_id

Tags: firebase, express, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, instagram-api

I'm trying to set up an instagram authentication process on my firebase application.
I followed the tutorial below : https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with/
And some people advised me to look at this : https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/Node-1st-gen/instagram-auth/functions/index.js

I use firebase functions on my backend which run with express (and node.js) not POSTMAN as I saw other people do.

The first step of my auth flow begin with a
`window.location()` which lead on my first firebase functions. The goal of this functions is to redirect me to instagram server and begin oauth2 process :

```
export const authToInstagram = functions.https.onRequest((req, res)=>{
  cookieParser()(req, res, ()=>{
    const oauth2 = instagramOAuthClient();
    // Generate a random state verification cookie.
    const state = req.cookies.state || makeid(64);
    res.cookie("state", state.toString(), {maxAge: 3600000, secure: true, httpOnly: true});
    const redirectUri = oauth2.authorizeURL({
      client_id: functions.config().instagram.client_id,
      redirect_uri: `${req.protocol}://us-central1-le-maki-55.cloudfunctions.net/instagramCallback`,
      scope: OAUTH_SCOPES,
      state: state,
    });
    res.redirect(redirectUri);
  });
});
```

It works well ; instagram log me in and ask for authorization to share data with my platform...
When this step is done instagram redirect to another firebase functions :

```
export const instagramCallback = functions.https.onRequest((req, res)=>{
  const oauth2 = instagramOAuthClient();
  return cookieParser()(req, res, ()=>{
    console.log(functions.config().instagram.client_id);
    fetch(req.url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "client_id": functions.config().instagram.client_id},
      body: JSON.stringify({client_id: functions.config().instagram.client_id}),
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("FETCH RESULT - body : "+data);
        });
    functions.logger.log("Received verification state:", req.cookies.state);
    functions.logger.log("Received state:", req.query.state);
    if (!req.cookies.state) {
      throw new Error("State cookie not set or expired. Maybe you took too long to authorize. Please try again.");
    } else if (req.cookies.state !== req.query.state) {
      throw new Error("State validation failed");
    }
    functions.logger.log("Received auth code:", req.query.code);
    if (req.query.code && req.query.code != "undefined") {
      const results = oauth2.getToken({
        code: req.query.code.toString(),
        redirect_uri: `${req.protocol}://us-central1-le-maki-55.cloudfunctions.net/instagramCallback`,
        scope: OAUTH_SCOPES,
      }).then((accessToken)=>{
        functions.logger.log("Auth code exchange result received:", results);
        // We have an Instagram access token and the user identity now.
        console.log("ACCESS TOKEN");
        console.log(accessToken);
        const access_Token = accessToken;
        const instagramUserID = accessToken.token.id;
        const profilePic = accessToken.token.profile_picture;
        const userName = accessToken.token.full_name;

        // Create a Firebase account and get the Custom Auth Token.
        createFirebaseAccount(instagramUserID, userName, profilePic, access_Token).then((token)=>{
          const firebaseToken = token;
          // Serve an HTML page that signs the user in and updates the user profile.
          return res.json({token: firebaseToken});
        });
      }, (error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      });
    } else {
      throw new Error("auth code exchange failed");
    }
  });
});
```

At this step oauth2 keep saying to my backend "ERROR : Missing required field client_id".
I checked my variables and they are set correctly with the basic display api client_id and secret...
I can see my client_id pass in the url params...
Some people say that it is because the client_id i snot in the body but I can't figure how to add the client_id inside the body in this process and I'm struggling with that issue from a couple week now.
Can somebody help me pls?

I tried to use fetch function but I'm not sure if it can really send data and didn't really understand it.

I also try the res.json() ans res.send but it end the functions.

I thought I could add the client_id directly in the redirector params but I couldn't...

I tried to use bodyParser.json() but still reach to the missing client_id error.

At last I really don't understand where to set it else.

Comment: Try replacing this line `headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "client_id": functions.config().instagram.client_id},` with just `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },` as you are sending client_id in headers which is not safe and secure

Comment: This is only for test... I wanted to be sure if my client_id was sent or not. But it don't fix my problem. Furthermore the code samples I see on the net don't even use a fetch functions. But it keep telling me missing client_id while it is set. What is the proper way to do it ?

Comment: My question is about why my body never contain my client_id ?